# Alternative to #define for flexibility in C

Tags: c, function, c-preprocessor

How can I structure some **C** code so that I don't have to laboriously go back and
    redefine (i.e., `#define`) things when I need to add a new item in the middle.
    Here is a code sample (in the real code, there are about 200 different
defines):

```
 #define CREAM   1
 #define SALT    2
 #define BUTTER  3
 #define SUGAR   4
 #define FAT     5

void healthyDiet()
{
    int length = 10;
    int menu[500];
    void consume(int, int);

    //   ******  these must be called in the following order only  
    consume( menu[ CREAM ],  length);
    consume( menu[ SALT ],   length);
    consume( menu[ BUTTER ], length);
    consume( menu[ SUGAR ],  length);
    consume( menu[ FAT ],    length);
}
```

But now I need to `#define` and add `LARD`, which would be straightforward if the sequence
    here were not important. But `LARD` must come before `SUGAR` and after `BUTTER`.  So
    I now need to edit the defines:

```
#define CREAM    1
#define SALT     2
#define BUTTER  3
#define LARD    4
#define SUGAR   5   // changed from 4
#define FAT     6   // changed from 5
```

So how
    can I structure things so that each time I want to add something in the middle, I
    don't have to go back and manually change the define value for each item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `enum`

```
enum {CREAM, SALT, BUTTER, LARD, SUGAR};
```

To add anoter element, just add it:

```
enum {CREAM, SALT, BUTTER, LARD, BACON, SUGAR};
```

You can even use this like a psudeo-iterator:

```
enum {FIRST_ONE, CREAM=0, SALT, BUTTER, LARD, BACON, SUGAR, LAST_ONE};

void healthyDiet()
{
    int length = 10;
    int menu[500];
    void consume(int, int);

    int x;
    for(x=FIRST_ONE; x<LAST_ONE; x++)
        consume( menu[ x ],  length);
}
```

Comment: So the FIRST_ONE will be equal to 0 (CREAM)? it makes sense.

Comment: @perreal: It does in gcc, but I'm not sure that that's defined behaviour.

Comment: For maximum hackery, `#define iterenum(name, ...) enum name { __VA_ARGS__, name##_LAST, name##_FIRST = 0 }`

Comment: @Dave.  Thank you...great time/energy saver.  Enum is new to me (I was an English major, and they never covered this at all in my Renaissance Poetry class).

Comment: @user994179 he defines a macro which inserts the first and last elements for you; so `iterenum(FOO, BAR, BAZ, QUUX);` becomes `enum FOO { BAR, BAZ, QUUX, FOO_LAST, FOO_FIRST=0};`

Comment: @user994179 - It automatically adds the iteration constants Dave's answer suggests. In fact, you could even `#define foreach(name, var) for(enum name var = name##_START; var < name##_END; var++)` which, with the `iterenum(FOO, ...)` type above, would make the code `foreach(FOO, i) { process(i); }` iterate over all the enum values. Some people might recommend against going overboard with control flow structures in macros, and they might be right. If you have several "groups" of constants, and frequently finding yourself iterating over them like this, `iterenum` and related macros may help.

Answer (score 3):

Check out enumerations:
http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/enum.html

```
enum {CREAM, SALT, BUTTER, LARD, BACON, SUGAR};
```